# Como hacer una bitácora en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo que registrar cada acción CRUD que se realice en cualquiera de las tablas de mi BD, pero necesito almacenar el usuario quien la realizó, mi pregunta es si ¿existe alguna funcionalidad de Laravel que facilite llevar ese registro o si es necesario realizarlo manualmente?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Algo asi? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213062/in-laravel-create-a-log-to-store-all-changes-of-resources

Comment: Recomiendo leas [ask], por otro lado Laravel si tiene algo referente en  la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events

Comment: Sí, mi pregunta seria exactamente esa.

Comment: Una ultima duda, los eventos solo se disparan si el crud se realiza con eloquent o tambien con query builder?

Comment: El tercer párrafo del enlace que te compartí resuelve esa duda, recomiendo lo leas a detalle

Comment: Muchas gracias, pregunta resuelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un observable para tus modelos el cual estará pendiente los los cabios en este, puedes crearlo usando php artisan de la siguiente manera

```
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

Hay muchos eventos que puede escuchar un Observable pero diría que los que estas buscando son los crear, editar y eliminar entonces el observable debe lucir mas o menos así:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Observers;
use App\User;
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the User "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        // Código para insertar en la tabla de auditoría
    }
    /**
     * Handle the User "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(User $user)
    {
        // Código para insertar en la tabla de auditoría
    }
    /**
     * Handle the User "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(User $user)
    {
        // Código para insertar en la tabla de auditoría
    }
}
```

Finamente tienes que registrar el observable en el método boot del AppServiceProvider que se encuentra en app/providers/AppServiceProvider

Debería lucir algo así:

```php
public function boot()
{
      User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

Enlaces relacionados:

https://gabrielchavez.me/observers-laravel

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023271/how-to-use-triggers-in-laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

Comment: Gracias por el aporte sin embargo considera que preguntas que no se ajustan a [ask] terminan cerradas, por ende el consejo es tratar de evitar responderlas

Comment: gracias, no sabia lo tendré en cuenta

Comment: Una duda, solo funciona si el crud se realiza mediante eloquent o también con query builder?